Form Attribute inturrpt javascript onchange event
The form has the id self_exam_form.
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="self_exam_form"></form>

I tried to push the input box inside the form by form attribute. The input box also has the onchange event. However, when I place the form attribute in the input field, the javascript function time_range() shows that the function is not defined. But if I remove the form="self_exam_form", it works.
<input type="range" min="2" max="60" value="0" name="time_range"
form="self_exam_form" onchange="time_range()" />


 function time_range(){
     //doing something
}

